# can't get the post values of req.body

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using Node.js and mongoose now I got stuck here :
The idea is to create a tour , I tested it with postman ,but I can't get anything from req.body .
I have tried body-parser,but dosen't work neighter ,what is going on?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "user-tour",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

**Tour SChema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
    type: String,
    required :[true,"A tour must have a name"],
    },
    rating :{
        type:Number,
        default : 4.5
    },
    price : {
        type : Number,
        required:[true,"A tour must have aprice"]
    }
    
});

const Tour = mongoose.model('Tour',tourSchema);
```

**TourController:** here ,I use req.body .And it suppose to get information from the client ,however ,it didn't get anything .Says,the name ,prcie etc are empty ..I have no idea what was going on .. Please help!!

```
exports.createTour = async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
      status:"success",
      data:{
        newTour
      }
    })
    
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status:'fail',
      message : error.message
    });
  }
};
```

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const tourRoute = require('./routes/tourRouts');
const userRoute = require('./routes/userRoutes');



app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use('/api/v1/tours',tourRoute);
app.use('/api/v1/users',userRoute);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


module.exports = app;
```

**Server.js**

```
 const app = require('./app');
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    dotenv.config();
    
    const port = process.env.PORT ||3000;
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,{ useNewUrlParser: true ,useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(()=>console.log("connecting mongoDB"))
    .catch(err => console.error("error :",err));
    app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('Backend server is running!');
    });
```

I am follwing MVC rule by the way ..

Comment: `body-parser` is needed for body buffer parsing, otherwise `req.body` will be undefined

Comment: @MarkoCen,hi bro ,thank you so much for your information .But how could I modify it on my code ? Could you please edit it ? Thank you so much for your patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in app.js, following changes will do the job.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //added
const morgan = require('morgan');
const tourRoute = require('./routes/tourRouts');
const userRoute = require('./routes/userRoutes');


// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use('/api/v1/tours',tourRoute);
app.use('/api/v1/users',userRoute);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


module.exports = app;
```